# append 1 Series (column) at the end of a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, series

I am working on a notebook with python/pandas, and I have:

- a Dataframe, X (with size **20550 rows × 18 columns**) and a
- a Series, a column, y (with size **20550**)
- I want to merge (or concatenate, append!) the column 'y' at the end of 'X'
- and have a X_total with size **20550 rows, 19 columns**

This is probably very simple but I am trying to append or concatenate horizontally, but I end up with dataframes with weird dimensions, at the best case I got a df with more rows (20551 rows × 20565 columns, or 20551 rows × 19 columns, full of NaNs)

EDIT:
I tried:

```
pd.concat([X,y], axis=1)
X.append(other=y)
dfsv=[X,y]
pd.concat([X,y], axis=1, join='outer', ignore_index=False)
X.append(y, ignore_index=True)
```

any thoughts?

cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append a Series as a column to a dataframe, the Series must have a name which will be used as the column name.  At the same time, the index of the Series need to match with the index of the dataframe.  As such, you can do it this way:

```
y2 = pd.Series(y.values, name='y', index=X.index)
X.join(y2)
```

Here, we fulfill 2 prerequisites at one step by defining a Series `y2` taking the values of Series `y`, give it the column name `y` and set its index to be the same as dataframe `X`.  Then, we can use [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to join `y2` at the end of `X`.

### Edit

#### Another even much simpler solution:

```
X['y'] = y.values
```

Answer (score 0):

If X and Y have same indices:

```
pd.concat([X, Y], axis=1)
```

If X and Y have different indices, you can try:

```
X.append(Y, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I edited above with the things I tried, it never returns: same number of rows * (18+1) column

Answer (score 0):

You can either append or con at. It is important though to specify the Axis to be columns

```
>>> X = pd.concat([X,Y], axis=1)
```

Comment: I edited above with the things I tried, it never returns: same number of rows * (18+1) column

Comment: Can you provide some sample? instead of these 100,000 rows - do a sample of X & Y with only 5 or 10 rows